# Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON in Visual Studio even when Azure Account is configured

Tags: .net-core, azure-active-directory, azure-sql-database, visual-studio-2019

We are using AD -interactive authentication to connect to sql.  The account has been configured in VS account manager with cloud explorer and sql server object explorer able to connect to the azure sql database resource.  However, when the application tries to connect in debug mode, we are seeing a "Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON'" error.  We tried removing and adding the azure account multiple times, and restarting visual studio.

This is a copy of our connection string "Data Source=xxxxxxxxx.database.windows.net;Initial Catalog=xxxxxx;Integrated Security=False;Connect Timeout=30;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;ApplicationIntent=ReadOnly;MultiSubnetFailover=False"

Language: c#
Framework: dotnet core 2.2
Library: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection

code:

```
_sqlAccessToken = (new AzureServiceTokenProvider()).GetAccessTokenAsync("https://database.windows.net/").Result;
  using (var conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString) { AccessToken = _sqlAccessToken })
            {
                var rawRecords = conn.Query<TModel>($"{dbSchema.ToString().ToLower()}.{storedProcName}", param, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure, commandTimeout: _commandtimeout).AsList();


 ...
```

_sqlAccessToken value is populated.  But VS is raising this exception
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON'.'

Comment: Have you added the user you used as Azure SQL AD admin? Regarding how to configure it, please refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-aad-authentication-configure

Comment: `_sqlAccessToken` being non-null does not mean it has found an Azure Service Identity, you need to also check its value.

Comment: @JimXu, this is an enterprise account.  We cannot just make a user an AD admin.

Comment: @Richard, the token contains a token string.

Answer (score 0):

When running under the debugger, the identity of the application is the same as the identity of the user running Visual Studio. This will not be a user with Azure Service Identity. You need to use a conventional user connection (SQL Login is the only option with Azure (managed) SQL, managed instances might have more options).

Azure Service/Application Identity only exists for certain resources running within Azure (this can include VMs, but only for, IIRC, where the system identity of the VM's OS).

NB. using `AzureServiceTokenProvider()` you are trying to get the current, if there is one, Azure Service Identity. This is not an Active Directory (AD) or Azure Active Directory (AAD) identity.

**Additional**

There is an option is VS to make use of an Azure Identity. See [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/service-to-service-authentication#authenticating-to-azure-services) (for KeyVault, but that's also using Azure Service Identity so should apply).

Comment: yes, I had my Azure identity configured in Visual Studio.  It was working as of yesterday, where it suddenly stopped working.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was, I had Visual Studio 2017 and 2019 installed with different Azure Accounts for each.  My 2019 VS was picking up the Azure Credentials from the 2017 installation.  When I opened up VS2017, signed out of all accounts, then the issue was resolved in VS2019